# How to Get value of filed "cat2" from the json string

Tags: java, json

How to Get value of filed `cat2` from the `json` string ..........

The code I have used to get the `json` string is mentioned below...

```
Gson gson = new Gson()
//convert java object to JSON format
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(json);
```

**....console output..........**

```
{
"feed": [
    {
        "cat1": "test",
        "cat2": "test",
        "cat3": "test",
        "title": "test"
    }
],
"bigimage": 0
}
```

What should I do further to get the value inside the `cat2` i.e `test` ?

Comment: The json String is just a representation of your object, in other words, the String you need is simply `obj.getFeed()[0].getCat2()` ? (or perhaps `obj.getFeed().get(0).getCat2()` if it's a list. All assuming you have apropriate getters in your object.

Comment: what does these two method contains getFeed() and getCat2()

Comment: You are using Gson to convert your `obj` into Json, via `String json = gson.toJson(obj);`. Thus it's only logical that your `obj` has a "feed" property which is a list/array of objects that have the variables cat1, cat2, cat3 and title. As long as the properties are not mapped differently, they should simply be accessable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();

JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

JsonArray feed = new JsonArray();
feed = jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("feed");

JsonObject jsonOb = feed.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
String value = jsonOb.get("cat2").getAsString();
```

This is how you can get `value` of `cat2`. You will need to add `com.google.gson` library to compile this code.

Comment: kruti on last two lines showing error i.e on JsonObject jsonObject = feed.getAsJsonObject(0); showing error to "remove argument to match getAsJsonObject() " and on String value = jsonObject.get("cat2"); showing to "change type of value to JsonElement"

Comment: @sourabhshukla: Corrected. My Bad.

Comment: @sourabhshukla: Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the below code and try:

```
JsonParser parser =  new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(data);
JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray feed = jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("feed");//get the feed arry from json
JsonObject jsonObject = feed.get(0).getAsJsonObject();//get the first feed element
System.out.println(jsonObject.get("cat2"));//displays test
```